# Proxy and SMTP connection from one server to another?

Tags: php, email, proxy

I have 2 servers, 1 is a small VPS with 128mb of RAM, the other is an old PC that I am running ubuntu on.

The old pc has way more ram and thus proves more useful but the only issue is that I cannot use php's mail() function as SMTP is blocked by my ISP.

I have heard on stackoverflow before that I can somehow make the 2 servers work together so I can send mail from the VPS while the script itself is on my old PC.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the PEAR library to connect to your remote SMTP server. Alternatively, you could use the Zend Framework's mail functions. PHPMailer is another option for you.

**PHPMAILER EXAMPLE**

```
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";        // SMTP account password

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

**PHP PEAR EXAMPLE**

```
include('Mail/smtp.php');

class MailHandler{

   var $params = null;
   var $mail_object = null;
   var $recipients = null;
   var $headers = null;
   var $body = "";

function MailHandler($host, $port, $auth, $username, $password, $persist) {
   $this->params["host"] = $host;
   $this->params["port"] = $port;
   $this->params["auth"] = $auth;
   $this->params["username"] = $username;
   $this->params["password"] = $password;
   $this->params["persist"] = $persist;

   // Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method
   //$this->mail_object =& Mail::factory('smtp', $this->params);
   $this->mail_object = new Mail_smtp($this->params);
}

function createFrom($email){
   $this->headers['From'] = $email;
}

function createTo($email){
   $this->headers['To'] = $email;
   $this->recipients = array($email);
}

function createCC($email){
   $this->headers['Cc'] = $email;
}

function createBCC($email){
   $this->headers['Bcc'] = $email;
}

function createSubject($sub){
   $this->headers['Subject'] = $sub;
}

function createBody($body){
   $this->body=$body;
}

function sendMail(){
   if ($this->mail_object->send($this->recipients, $this->headers, $this->body)) {
      return true;
   }else{
      return false;
   }
}

}



$smtpserver_host = "localhost"; // The server to connect. Default is localhost
$smtpserver_Port = 25; // The port to connect. Default is 25
$smtpserver_auth = FALSE; // Whether or not to use SMTP authentication. Default is FALSE
$smtpserver_username = "username"; // The username to use for SMTP authentication.
$smtpserver_password = "password"; // The password to use for SMTP authentication.
$smtpserver_persist = FALSE; // Indicates whether or not the SMTP connection should persist over multiple calls to the send() method.
$mailhandler=new MailHandler($smtpserver_host, $smtpserver_Port, $smtpserver_auth, $smtpserver_username, $smtpserver_password, $smtpserver_persist);

$mailhandler->createTo("toaddress");
$mailhandler->createFrom("fromaddress");
$mailhandler->createSubject("subject");
$mailhandler->createBody("body");

if($mailhandler->sendMail()){
   echo "Mail sent.\n";
}else{
   echo "Error sending mail!\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: could i just edit php's configuration and point it to my VPS?

Comment: Nope :-( It's not possible to edit the php.ini file to use a remote SMTP server. I would highly recommend using the PEAR or Zend Libraries to solve your problem.

Comment: Is PEAR being installed on your Ubuntu machine?

Comment: another question is how do i obtain the credentials for SMTP? I have never edited it. The SMTP was setup when i bought the VPS

Comment: sudo apt-get install php-pear - run that on your Ubuntu machine and it will install it.

Comment: You should be able to get your SMTP credentials from your VPS provider.

Comment: the thing is i dont own the VPS, it was given to me for a year actually as a gift...

Comment: ok well just try using the VPS's IP address, port 25 and check that the firewall is allowing connections

Comment: wait can u back up a bit, what do i need to do on my local server first so i can make that file u posted? im a bit lost

Comment: You need to make sure PEAR is installed - so run the command: sudo apt-get install php-pear then you can use the example above. Here's a link to an PEAR install guide on Ubuntu http://stuffthatspins.com/2010/02/26/ubuntu-install-pear/

Comment: wait, would phpmailer work? I still am having issues with credentials

Comment: Yes it will - i've added a PHP Mailer code example to my answer.

Comment: ok, i just need to find my credentials now... so far this is what im getting "SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) " is this credential based?

Comment: Could be that the firewall port isn't open to allow connections to the SMTP server. You'll need to open it.

Comment: im trying to enable the postfix config too allow authentication but it isnt working... any help

Comment: it's hard to help with something like that - can't see the errors, etc. I would suggest Googling to see how to setup POSTFIX for Authentication

Comment: I followed: http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-natty-narwhal-ubuntu-11.04-ispconfig-2-p5 but got: 250-AUTH=PLAIN CRAM-MD5 NTLM LOGIN DIGEST-MD5 instead of: 250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN what did i do wrong?